# Find scalar product of leg and side of right triangle

Tags: geometry

From the figure  below
[image]

It is given that length of `$BC=3#` we are asked to find scalar product of vectors $AB$ and $BC$

I don't know  methods to solve such problems and please help me.

Comment: I can't parse this. Where's your origin located?

Comment: aa ok see this   it is written in georgian language but question is the same as i wrote see it   http://www.naec.ge/images/doc/MASC_SERT/2011pedagogebi-matematikai.pdf  number 19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by scalar product, you mean dot product, then the answer would be $-9$.  The definition of cosine says $|\vec{BC}|=|\vec{AB}|\cos(\angle ABC)$; note that $cos(\angle ABC)>0$ since it is acute.  Since $\vec{BA}\cdot\vec{BC}=|\vec{BC}||\vec{AB}|\cos(\angle ABC)$ and $\vec{AB}=-\vec{BA}$, we get that $\vec{BA}\cdot\vec{BC}=-|\vec{BC}|^2$.

Comment: how this equality does hold?BA*BC=|BC||AB|cos(∠ABC)

Comment: sorry i understood

Comment: thanks very much @robjohn i have seen everything and got right answer  you answer helped very much thanks ones again